# How may the following equlity show up?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was trying to find what was the nature of the following series: $u_n=\frac{n^n}{\sqrt{n!)^\alpha}}$

I was stuck, I looked at the correction given by the book. But I was still missing something: I was wondering why:

> $$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{[(n+1)!]^{\alpha}}
> }\cdot\frac{\sqrt{(n!)^\alpha}}{n^n} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\cdot (n+1)^{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}.$$

in order to use the rule of d'Alembert.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0yt0.jpg)

I tried to find it on my own but wasn't able to find it out...

Comment: Does this help? $\frac{\sqrt{(n!)^\alpha}}{\sqrt{((n+1)!)^\alpha}}=\sqrt{\frac{(n!)^\alpha}{((n+1)!)^\alpha}}=(n+1)^{-\alpha/2}$.

Comment: "The ratio of square-roots is the square-root of the ratio":  exchange the denominators so that the square-roots are in one ratio, then write that as the square-root of the entire ratio and simplify the expression under the radical.  For the other ratio, you will have $$ \( \frac{n+1}{n} \)^n \ \cdot \ (n+1) \ \ , $$ which can also be simplified.

Comment: It is very easy. Try to see why.

Comment: Please, edit the "word" *correctection* to make its meaning clear.